# When I tried to selection with SHIFT + arrow at keyboard in Android studio on Pro M1 MAX it works like ALT key

Tags: android-studio, apple-m1, shift

I have a new Macbook Pro M1 MAX and installed Android Studio. I tried to select substring on line in Android Studio but it does not work. When I press and hold `SHIFT` key on keyboard, typing pointer changed and work as like I hold ALT key.

- When I use double keys(`CMD` + `SHIFT`, `ALT` + `SHIFT` ) it works.
- When I use different program (Sublime, EditText, etc.) it works.
- When I use only `SHIFT`, it does not work.

Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

I found solution.

- removed every plugin on Android Studio and it is works.
- Add every plugin step by step and check after every plugin installation

And Baaam!

Problem is "IdeaVim" plugin.

When installed shift key works like a crazy :)

Comment: Jeesus I lost quite a few minutes trying to figure out what the hell was going on with my IDE. I didn't install IdeaVim. No idea how it ended up there and I was going crazy mad with the keyboard behavior. TY!